# Get Logistic regressions odds from equation result

Tags: logistic, classification, spss

By using logistic regression in SPSS I get an equation that looks like this:

```
 0.1535 * X1+ 
 -0.0002973 * X2 + 
 -114.9 * X3 + 
 -114.0 * X4
```

How do I transform the result of the equation to the odds of the classifier (between 0 and 1) using SQL?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `EXP()` to convert the `logs odds` to `odds`.

Example: `EXP(-1.30) = 0.27` then `EXP(logs odds)/(1+EXP(logs odds))`

i.e.

```
Probability = (0.27)/(1+0.27) = 0.21
```

To see how to use `EXP` in SQL see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179857.aspx)

Hope this helps !

Comment: The following equation works for some of the values:
Probability=EXP(Equation Result)/(1+EXP(Equation Result))

But for values of EXP(Equation Result) that are greater than 1 the method doesn't work, do you have am idea why

Comment: That should work. Can you please give me an example and what error are you getting?

Comment: Sure:
EXP(-1.062)/(1+EXP(-1.062)) = 0.74 --> works fine

EXP(0.2215)/(1+EXP(0.2215)) = 0.44 --> wrong odds --> should be 0.55

EXP(4.9)/(1+EXP(4.9)) = 0.17 --> wrong odds --> should be 0.83

Comment: hmmm.. that's strange.. The formula does not change for each row. So there is nothing wrong with formula. I doubt something wrong with the data type.

Comment: Found the correct method
If (Equation Results)<0 then:
probability=EXP(Equation Results)/(1+EXP(Equation Results))

If (Equation Results)>=0 then:
probability=1-EXP(Equation Results)/(1+EXP(Equation Results))

Comment: No need to change the formula. Formula in the answer should give you the correct results irrespective of the signs of the value. see this http://www.pmean.com/13/predicted.html